# Hyperlinks dont work in Captivate 6 when imported from powerpoint

Tags: hyperlink, adobe-captivate, powerpoint-2013

We are trying to create a captivate 6 presentation by importing a powerpoint 2013 presentation that has hyperlinks in it. However, it seems that the hyperlinks don't work when the project is published as a swf file. When you mouse over the hyperlink, the mouse changes the cursor to a hand, but when you click it, nothing happens ? Any ideas on what could be the problem or the fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Captivate doesn't understand text hyperlinks; place a click box over the link and assign it the action 'Open URL or file' to accomplish this.

Note: the dropdown immediately to the right of the URL input box allows you to set the target of the link, and whether or not the presentation will be played/paused upon clicking.